# $ {{\int} f(\textbf {xt})\ d\lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (\textbf {t}) = |xy| {\int} f(\textbf {t})\ d\lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (\textbf {t})}.$

Tags: measure-theory, proof-writing, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

> For any non-negative Borel measurable function $f : \Bbb R^2 \longrightarrow \Bbb R,$ $$\displaystyle {\int} f(\textbf {xt})\ d\lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (\textbf {t}) = |xy| \displaystyle {\int} f(\textbf {t})\ d\lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (\textbf {t}),$$
> where for $\textbf {x} = (x,y)$ and $\textbf {t} = (r,s),$ $\textbf {xt} : = (xr,ys).$

Let us first assume that both the components of $\textbf {x}$ i.e. both $x$ and $y$ be non-zero. If we can prove the above result for indicator function of Borel measurable subsets of $\Bbb R^2$ then we are through. Because then by linearity of Lebesgue integral and by Monotone convergence theorem the result continues to hold for any non-negative Borel measurable function.

Let $A \in \mathcal B_{\Bbb R^2}.$ Let $f = \chi_A.$ Then $\textbf {xt} \in A \iff \textbf {t} \in \left (\frac 1 x, \frac 1 y \right ) A.$ Since $A \in \mathcal B_{\Bbb R^2},$ it follows that $\left (\frac 1 x, \frac 1y \right ) A \in \mathcal B_{\Bbb R^2}$ and $\lambda_{\Bbb R^2} \left (\left (\frac 1 x, \frac 1y \right ) A \right ) = \frac {\lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (A)} {|xy|}.$ So we have $\chi_A (\textbf {xt}) = \chi_{\left (\frac 1 x, \frac 1 y \right ) A} (\textbf {t}),$ for all $\textbf {t} \in \Bbb R^2.$ Hence we have $$\displaystyle {\int} \chi_A(\textbf {xt})\ d\lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (\textbf {t}) = \displaystyle {\int} \chi_{\left (\frac 1 x, \frac 1 y \right ) A} (\textbf {t})\ d\lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (\textbf {t}) = \lambda_{\Bbb R^2} \left (\left (\frac 1 x, \frac 1y \right ) A \right ) = \frac {\lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (A)} {|xy|}.$$ On the other hand $$\displaystyle {\int} \chi_A (\textbf {t})\ d\lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (\textbf {t}) = \lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (A).$$ So we have $$\displaystyle {\int} \chi_A (\textbf {xt})\ d\lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (\textbf {t}) = \frac {1} {|xy|} \displaystyle {\int} \chi_A (\textbf {t})\ d\lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (\textbf {t}).$$ Which is not matching with the equation I intended to prove. Where have I made mistake? Also how do I tackle the case where both the components of $\textbf {x}$ are not simultaneously non-zero? Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you know the formula for change of variables $\int_{g(U)}f(y)\,dy=\int_U f(g(x))|J_g(x)|\,dx$ in the context of Lebesgue integration?

Comment: What you have proved is correct. The original equality you intended to prove is in fact false. Also if any component of $(x, y)$ is zero, then weird thing can happen (which you would expect looking at what you have proved). For example let $(x, y)=(x, 0)$ for some $x.$ And take $f(\mathbf{t}=(t_1, t_2))=1$ if $t_2=0$ and $0$ otherwise. Clearly, $\int f(\mathbf{t}) d\lambda_2(\mathbf{t})=0.$ On the other hand, $f(\mathbf{x}\mathbf{t})=1$ for all $\mathbf{t}\in \mathbb{R}^2$ which tells you that $\int f(\mathbf{x}\mathbf{t})d\lambda_{2}(\mathbf{t})=\infty.$

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho this problem has been left as an exercise in my book *An Introduction to Measure and Integration* (**Second Edition**) by Inder K. Rana (published by American Mathematical Society) at Page no. **231** Exercise **7.4.5. (ii)**. Kindly check sir.

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho so what I proves continues to hold for any non-negative Borel measurable function because Lebesgue integral is linear and Monotone convergence theorem holds. Or in other words for any Borel measurable function $f : \Bbb R^2 \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ and for any $\textbf {x} = (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2$ with $x \neq 0 \wedge y \neq 0$ we have the following $:$ $$\displaystyle {\int} f (\textbf {xt})\ d\lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (\textbf {t}) = \frac {1} {|xy|} \displaystyle {\int} f(\textbf {t}) d\lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (\textbf {t}).$$ Am I right sir?

Comment: I don't think it's correct @WhoKnowsWho sir. Because every continuous function is Borel measurable. So if we take any non-negative continuous function then it is non-negative Borel measurable. If we consider the function $f : \Bbb R^2 \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ defined by $$f(\textbf {t} = (r,s)) = r^2s^2,\ r,s \in \Bbb R.$$ Then $f$ is a non-negative continuous function and hence non-negative Borel measurable. Now if we take $\textbf {x} = (1,2)$ then we have $$\int f(\textbf {xt})\ d\lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (\textbf {t}) = 4 \int f(\textbf {t})\ d\lambda_{\Bbb R^2} (\textbf {t}).$$

Comment: @WhoKnowsWho can you please tell me where have I made mistake? By the way in the above example I'm restricting the domain to $[0,1] \times [0,1].$

Comment: @Phibetakappa As I remarked earlier your derivation for $\int f(\mathbf{x}\mathbf{t})d\mathbf{t}=\frac{1}{|xy|}\int f(\mathbf{t})d\mathbf{t}$ is correct. In your previous example, $f(\mathbf{t}=(r, s))=r^2s^2$ is not integrable over $\mathbb{R}^2,$ that is $\int f(\mathbf{t}d\mathbf{t})=\infty.$

Comment: If you restrict $f(\mathbf{t})=r^2s^2\Xi_{[0, 1]\times [0, 1]}(\mathbf{t}),$ then you need to be careful with the domain of your integral while changing the variables. Do it more carefully and you will see@